# how can I persist state on React-Bootstrap Accordion using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to save the state of a React-Bootstrap Accordion in localStorage using useState hook.

Using the example on the React-Bootstrap [docs website](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/) I know I can get the eventKey and control it using this. Using the examples on the website, which use the eventKey to customise a toggle button is slightly different from what I need and I can't seem to make the leap between them. I can save the eventKey to localStorage but I can't get it back into the eventKey prop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would utilize the `<Accordion>` components `onSelect` prop and pass a function where you update a Hook's state and save that eventKey to localStorage.

```
const [expandedItem, setExpandedItem] = useState("0")

...

<Accordion
    defaultActiveKey={expandedItem}
    onSelect={(e) => {
        if (e !== null){ // if e === null, that means that an accordion item was collapsed rather than expanded. e will be non-null when an item is expanded
            setExpandedItem(e);
            localStorage.setItem('expandedItem', e);
        }
    }
...
```

And if you wanted to have this Accordion open to the last item that was expanded by the user on page re-renders, you could amend the above to achieve that behavior:

```
const [expandedItem, setExpandedItem] = useState(localStorage.getItem('expandedItem') ?? "0")
```

`??` is the [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#Relationship_with_the_optional_chaining_operator_).

Let me know if this answers your question. If this isn't really what you were looking for, maybe you can edit your original post with some more details or a code sample.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This doesn't seem to work. onSelect doesn't fire, so i used onClick, and localStorage gets populated with [object, object]. What I can't seem to work out, is how do I get the value of "0" for collapsed item or "1" for expanded Item from the <Accordion eventKey /> in order to store it in localStorage. The (e) in your example will not give me this.

Comment: Hmm... the onSelect() method seemed to work on the code editor in the in-line editors from the docs page you linked as well as this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-morse-579xf?file=/src/App.js). My initial guess as to why it's not working for you is different versions (I believe I used v1.4.3). Nonetheless, I would print the response you get from the onClick. Try printing each of the indices to see if you are getting back expected results.

Comment: With this component in particular, only 1 item will be expanded at any moment. So, if the returned eventKey means that an item just expanded, you know the rest are collapsed, and thus you only need to store that key in localStorage. Let me know if this helps. Maybe you can link a CodeSandbox that mimics what you are working with.

Comment: The Code Sandbox was a big help, thanks! I was able to work through yours and apply it to my scenario, with a couple of tweaks. Firstly I ran in to problems with the Nullish Coalescing Operator. My version of Babel did not like it and it caused me all sorts of problems so I ditched it. [my Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/persist-state-accordion-94ql8).

Comment: I noticed you never use setExpandedItem, is there a reason for this? Also, I thought you are supposed to handle localStorage setting and getting inside a useEffect hook, is this not the case?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I wasn't able to run localStorage calls in my Sandbox because the Sandbox isn't able to fully emulate a browser. So I had commented out the lines where I was setting and getting the "expandedItem" item. Let me also just say that you did well to replace the `??` with your own ternary operator - nice! As per the use of the setExpandedItem hook, I used it in my Sandbox on line 18.

Comment: ... A hook's state will persist until the page is refreshed. Once refreshed, everything is re-rendered from scratch, unless you have some method of storing that information in the browser. This is why you use localStorage. So although I utilize the setExpandedItem hook, it would be useless unless I didn't also store the new eventKey in local storage. In my experience, I've used useEffect for asynchronous API calls and localStorage is usually quick enough that it is instant, however you certainly could utilize useEffect to update the state with a call to localStorage.

Comment: Really nice explanation. Thanks, I was overthinking how to go about it and based what I was trying to do, on another example using useEffect hook forgetting, it's mainly for use with asynchronous logic rather than localStorage. I've updated my Sandbox also, and replaced the setExpandedItem by de-structuring useState hook since we aren't explicitly using it.